# Disabling System Tray icon in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt4, system-tray

I have application with `QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon` and a Qmenu in it. Is there a way to disable and enable it.

I want this to disable when my application is launching, so that user have no option to access the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

There are `.show()` and `.hide()` methods and a `.visible` property that allows to show or hide a `QSystemTrayIcon`.
Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: i am looking to disable the tray icon. It should be visiable but nit accessable. like when we disable out antivirus. we see grayout icon

Comment: I don't think there's a way to "disable" a tray icon. What you should try to do instead, is to set a custom icon (which you will gray out separately) and disable the context menu on the tray icon.